# Any Expected condition for when an item is seleted? Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, protractor, expected-condition

I am testing a checkbox, and i want to know if there is any expected condition to wait for the item to be selected. Right now on my tests i am using browser.sleep with 10 seconds(the checkbox takes to much time to load) but that doesnt seems the good.

Can anyone help me?

I have this:

```
 it('the tick of element is selected should be visible', () => {
    browser.sleep(5000);
    //  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(locator.lateCancelCheckbox),5000);
      browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(locator.lateCancelCheckbox1),7000);
      locator.lateCancelCheckbox1.click();
      browser.sleep(10000);
      expect(locator.lateCancelCheckbox.getAttribute('class')).toEqual('checkbox checkbox-md ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

have you even checked the docs? the info is literally there:

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeSelected

Comment: Ohh, i readed that wrong, I though that expected condition was before the item was selected. Thanks!